# What to supply to scatter3D as Y and Z?

Tags: r, scatter3d

I have some data:

```
> head(dat)
   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14
1:  2  2  3  2  4  1  1  0  0   0   2   2   0   0
2:  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0
3:  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0
4:  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0
5:  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   1   1   0   0
6:  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0
```

How can I create a 3D plot of this data, so X axis would be `V1:V14`, Y axis would be `1:6(Index)` and Z axis would be the value of `V1[1]`?

When I try to plot I get:

```
> scatter3D(dat)
Error in range(y, na.rm = TRUE) : 'y' is missing
```

What should I parse as Y and Z?

Comment: which library is `scatter3d` from?

Comment: [scatter3d](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/scatterplot3d/index.html), I don't mind using any other library

Comment: Can you provide additional explanation of what you're trying to do? For a 3D scatterplot, wouldn't you plot 3 variables (columns) at a time (e.g., V1, V2, and V3). These would be the x, y, and z values.

Comment: `scatter3d` is in the `car` package. You could also try the `rgl` package and use the `plot3d` function to produce an animated plot that you can rotate. For a static plot, you could try the `scatterplot3d` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to play around with the arguments, but `wireframe` is nice.

```
library(lattice)
d <- as.matrix(dat)
wireframe(d, scales = list(arrows = FALSE),
          drape = TRUE, colorkey = TRUE,
          screen = list(z = 30, x = -60))
```

[image]